# Ubuntu 22.04 login screen not showing problem on Virtualbox

Tags: boot, nvidia, virtualbox, login

I'm using windows 10 and I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on virtualbox.

After loading, the Ubuntu screen displays a partial login page only including an Ubuntu logo below, but none of the other elements. The preview of the virtual machine program displays the same screen.
If I change the size of screen at this time, the screen goes all black. But the preview of the virtual machine program displays a complete login page, unlike before.

If I go to recovery mode and resume, Ubuntu works normally.
But I don't want to use recovery mode every booting time.

I guessed the graphic driver or capacity is the problem, but i'm not sure.
I'm not sure about that it's about Ubuntu or Virtual machine too.
How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm also running many Linux distros in Win10 via Virtualbox, but never encounter this issue. You may try choosing another `Graphics Controller` by going to the VM's Settings -> Display.

Comment: Merilyn, I tried VMSVGA for my graphics controller and it displays the login page normally. But I want to use VBoxVGA controller cuz of the screen flexibility. VMSVGA only provides me too small screen. But your suggestion was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Screen size is unrelated to the controller and in any case you want to install the guest additions.

Comment: ChanganAuto,  I installed the guest additions manually with VMSVGA and it works properly. I didn't noticed that because VboxVGA or VboxSVGA seemed to operate the guest additions automatically. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

I changed the VBox Graphics controller to VMSVGA then things started working fine for me.